# Tensorflow keras - How to avoid erroring out when loading h5 model if model is not present

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am writing an application which trains machine learning models ad-hoc, when I try to fetch the model like so:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./models/model.h5')
```

I get an error:

```
Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'models/model.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

In some special cases however the model might not be present on disk, at which point it should be created, trained and saved for later use. What would be the right approach to checking if a model is present? I could use inbuilt functionality in python to check if the file exists but it seems obvious to me that there should be a parameter on load_model which returns None instead of throwing error if the file is not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python way of checking if the file exists is the right way to go.

This may be personal, but it's not obvious that `None` should be returned. When you open a file, the file must exist.

You can:

```
import os.path

if os.path.isfile(fname):
    model=load_model(fname)
else:
    model = createAndTrainModel()
```

Or you can

```
try:
    model=load_model(fname)
except:
    model = createAndTrainModel()
```

I prefer the first.

Comment: try:
                return tf.keras.models.load_model('./models/model.h5')
            except OSError: is the current approach I do, specyfing the exact exception, but it's extra code which I don't like, I am used to just get a null in situations like that.